# Imagen se sobrepone a mi slidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css

Le pongo position relative a mi contenedor de banner y mi la imagen se sobrepone a mi slidebar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: intenta poniendo z-index: 9999 a tu slidebar

Comment: Gracias me funciono

Comment: El código siempre _como texto, con formato_. Haz que tu pregunta sea también útil para los demás usuarios: pulsa en [edit] para mejorarla. Lee [ask].

Comment: @JorgeAlmada ¡ponlo como respuesta! Así OP puede [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer).